Is there a python equivalent of process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR if firebase functions?
I'm trying to find a way to check if the current running environment is the emulator in firebase functions v2 for python. The way to do this in js/ts is to use process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR. However, I have not been able to find a way to do this for python.

Did you try os.environ.get('FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR')?
